# Unable to record the score and high score properly

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm tryin to make a snake game, but I am unable to record the score and high-score properly. Whenever the snake collects an item, all that happens is that the high score increases, but not the general score.

```
from tkinter import *
from settings import *
import random
import turtle
import pygame as pg
import keyboard
from os import path

global game_state 

class Snake:

    def __init__(self):
        self.body_size = BODY_PARTS
        self.coordinates = []
        self.squares = []

        for i in range(0, BODY_PARTS):
            self.coordinates.append([0, 0])

        for x, y in self.coordinates:
            square = canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x + SPACE_SIZE, y + SPACE_SIZE, fill=SNAKE_COLOR, tag="snake")
            self.squares.append(square)


class Food:

    def __init__(self):

        x = random.randint(0, (GAME_WIDTH / SPACE_SIZE)-1) * SPACE_SIZE
        y = random.randint(0, (GAME_HEIGHT / SPACE_SIZE) - 1) * SPACE_SIZE

        self.coordinates = [x, y]

        canvas.create_oval(x, y, x + SPACE_SIZE, y + SPACE_SIZE, fill=FOOD_COLOR, tag="food")

class TryAgain:

    def __init__(self):
        x = (GAME_WIDTH / SPACE_SIZE)-1 * SPACE_SIZE
        y = (GAME_HEIGHT / SPACE_SIZE) - 1 * SPACE_SIZE
        self.coordinates = [x, y]

def show_title_screen():
    canvas.create_text(canvas.winfo_width()/2, canvas.winfo_height()/4,
                       font=('times new roman',70), text="SNAKE!", fill="Green", tag="title")

    canvas.create_text(canvas.winfo_width()/2, canvas.winfo_height()/2,
                       font=('times new roman',22), text="Use the arrow keys to move", fill="Green", tag="title")


def next_turn(snake, food):

    x, y = snake.coordinates[0]

    if direction == "up":
        y -= SPACE_SIZE
    elif direction == "down":
        y += SPACE_SIZE
    elif direction == "left":
        x -= SPACE_SIZE
    elif direction == "right":
        x += SPACE_SIZE

    snake.coordinates.insert(0, (x, y))

    square = canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x + SPACE_SIZE, y + SPACE_SIZE, fill=SNAKE_COLOR)

    snake.squares.insert(0, square)

    if x == food.coordinates[0] and y == food.coordinates[1]:

        global score
        global high_score

        score += 1
        label.config(text="Score:{}".format(score))

        if score >= high_score:
            high_score = score
            label.config(text="High Score:{}".format(high_score))

        canvas.delete("food")

        food = Food()

    else:

        del snake.coordinates[-1]

        canvas.delete(snake.squares[-1])

        del snake.squares[-1]

    if check_collisions(snake):
        game_over()

    else:
        window.after(SPEED, next_turn, snake, food)
    

def change_direction(new_direction):

    global direction

    if new_direction == 'left':
        if direction != 'right':
            direction = new_direction
    elif new_direction == 'right':
        if direction != 'left':
            direction = new_direction
    elif new_direction == 'up':
        if direction != 'down':
            direction = new_direction
    elif new_direction == 'down':
        if direction != 'up':
            direction = new_direction


def check_collisions(snake):

    x, y = snake.coordinates[0]

    if x < 0 or x >= GAME_WIDTH:
        return True
    elif y < 0 or y >= GAME_HEIGHT:
        return True

    for body_part in snake.coordinates[1:]:
        if x == body_part[0] and y == body_part[1]:
            return True

    return False


def game_over():

    canvas.delete(ALL)
    canvas.create_text(canvas.winfo_width()/2, canvas.winfo_height()/4,
                       font=('times new roman',70), text="GAME OVER", fill="orange", tag="gameover")
    button = TryAgain()

def load_data(self):
    self.dir = path.dirname(__dirname__)
    with open(path.join(self.dir, HS_FILE), 'w') as f:
        try:
            self.highscore = int(f.read())
        except:
            self.highscore = 0

window = Tk()
window.title("Snake game")
window.resizable(False, False)

score = 0
high_score = 0
direction = 'down'

label = Label(window, text="Score:{}".format(score), font=('times new roman', 40))
label.pack()
label = Label(window, text="High Score:{}".format(high_score), font=('times new roman', 40))
label.pack()

canvas = Canvas(window, bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR, height=GAME_HEIGHT, width=GAME_WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

window.update()

window_width = window.winfo_width()
window_height = window.winfo_height()
screen_width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = window.winfo_screenheight()

x = int((screen_width/2) - (window_width/2))
y = int((screen_height/2) - (window_height/2))

window.geometry(f"{window_width}x{window_height}+{x}+{y}")

show_title_screen()

window.bind('<Left>', lambda event: change_direction('left'))
window.bind('<Right>', lambda event: change_direction('right'))
window.bind('<Up>', lambda event: change_direction('up'))
window.bind('<Down>', lambda event: change_direction('down'))

snake = Snake()
food = Food()

next_turn(snake, food)

window.mainloop()
```

In one instance, I tried to rearrange the canvas codes that involved "score" and "high score", and tried to make it so that when the high score is greater than the score, it would start counting, but that still doesn't work.

Comment: What actual output are you seeing from the code that makes you think score is not being updated?

Comment: Say you want to collect one item. If you do, you get this outout:

Score: 0
High Score: 1

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about tkinter.  But I think the problem is due to this:

```
label = Label(window, text="Score:{}".format(score), font=('times new roman', 40))
label.pack()
label = Label(window, text="High Score:{}".format(high_score), font=('times new roman', 40))
label.pack()
```

You're using the same variable name for both labels.

And then when you update the scores:

```
score += 1
label.config(text="Score:{}".format(score))

if score >= high_score:
    high_score = score
    label.config(text="High Score:{}".format(high_score))
```

The variable name `label` refers only to the high score label.

I think you can fix this by using different variable names for the two labels, i.e. something like `score_label` and `high_score_label`.